# Cosa significa "tempate" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Con Silvana ci fu un flirtarello, nelle lunghe sere di accampamento fra gli acquitrini, tormentate da nuvole di zanzare, **tempate** dagli strdii dei grilli e delle ranocchie.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "tempate" in questa frase. Ho cercato "tempato" e "tempare", ma non ho trovato niente nei dizionari che ho consultato. Mi sapreste spiegare qual è il significato di questo termine?

Comment: Una brutta scelta linguistica, ma sono d'accordo con CasaMich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credo che *tempate* sia da considerare in questo contesto un sinonimo di *ritmate*.
Lo deduco dal fatto che tempo e ritmo sono sinonimi in molti casi e gli strdii dei grilli e delle ranocchie sono suoni ritmici.

Certamente la parola non ha questo significato nell'italiano corrente, ma il senso in questa frase è chiaro.